# Spark - Fetch Hbase table all versions data using HBase Spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

Need to fetch all the versions of HBase table using the connector "**org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark**".
This only returns the latest version always. Need a way to fetch all versions while reading it into Spark dataframe

Cloudera distribution: 7.1.8

Hbase Version: 2.4

Spark version: 3.3

Configured the Hbase Spark connector by following the cloudera blogs:

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.8/accessing-hbase/topics/hbase-configure-spark-connector.html

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.8/accessing-hbase/topics/hbase-example-using-hbase-spark-connector.html

HBase Table:

```
scan 'test', {VERSIONS=\>3}
ROW                                        COLUMN+CELL
row1                                      column=cf:data, timestamp=1970-01-01T05:30:00.003, value=value3
row1                                      column=cf:data, timestamp=1970-01-01T05:30:00.002, value=value2
row1                                      column=cf:data, timestamp=1970-01-01T05:30:00.001, value=value1
```

There's one row(row1) with 3 version for data("value1","value2","value3").

Below spark code to fetch the "test" table

Spark code:

```
val hbase_column_mapping = "device String :key, data STRING cf:data"
val hbase_table = "test"

val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
.option("hbase.columns.mapping", hbase_column_mapping)
.option("hbase.table", hbase_table)
.option("hbase.spark.query.maxVersions", 3)
.option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false)
.load()
```

```
df.show()

Output is:
+------+------+
|  data|device|
+------+------+
|value3|  row1|
+------+------+
```

Even after providing the conf "**hbase.spark.query.maxVersions**", still it fetches only the latest version. Requirement is to fetch all versions from Hbase table in Spark. In the above case it should fetch 3 records for 3 versions.

```
Expected:
+------+------+
|  data|device|
+------+------+
|value1|  row1|
|value2|  row1|
|value3|  row1|
+------+------+
```